# How can I not allow letters, and only allow numbers in an input on python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I am a beginner. I'm making a survey, and one of the questions asks the users age. How can I make it so that if the user enters a letter or symbol, it shows a print() message?

The issue seems to be that the computer reads the first if statement of "if age < 10:" and then sends an error message in the terminal if I enter a string.

This is the code right now, I want it so that if the user inputs a letter(s) or symbol(s), it sends a print() message, and asks for the input again, is that possible?

```
c = 3

while c == 3:
    age = int(input('How old are you (enter a number)? '))
    if age < 10:
        print("Wow, you're quite young!")
        break
    elif age > 60 and age <= 122:
        print("Wow, you're quite old!")
        break
    elif age > 122:
        print('Amazing! You are the oldest person in history! Congrats!')
        break
    elif age >= 14 and age <= 18:
        print('Really? You look like a college student!')
        break
    elif age >= 10 and age <= 13:
        print('Really? You look like a 10th grader!')
        break
    elif age > 18 and age <= 60:
        print('Really? No way! You look younger than that, could have fooled me!')
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Define each operation in your survey as a different function. Then you can use a statement like this one:

```
try:
    int(input_variable)
except ValueError:
    function()
```

To check if they gave you an integer, and if they didn't they have to input again. You seem to be a beginner so I can answer questions if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

for simple solution, simply loop until integers are received.

```
while True:
  try:
    age = int(input('How old are you (enter a number)? '))
  except ValueError:
    print('input should be integer!')
    continue
  break
```